# persist fields order for linux `top`

Tags: linux

In linux, `top` can be used to monitor system status. When it is running, using `f` allows us to choose the columns to be displayed.

However, when you quit it and reenter `top`, all the settings go back to the default.

How can I make the changes persistent? Is there a config file for `top`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **W** (capital w) to save the top configuration after you made your changes.
By issuing this command just before quitting top, you will be able restart later in exactly that same state (from **man** page)